# What is the difference between SGI slist and C++11 forward_list?

Tags: list, c++11, containers, singly-linked-list

Both SGI `slist` and C++11 `std::forward_list` appear identical to me unless I have missed something; both implement a singly-linked list.

I assume there is a difference though as the C++ Standard Commitee didn't adopt the name slist and instead chose a new name, forward_list, when they added the container into the Standard Library for C++0x.

Comment: The main difference being that forward_list objects are single-linked lists, and thus they can only be iterated forwards, in exchange for being somewhat smaller and more efficient. std::list is Doubly-linked list

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One major difference is that `std::forward_list` lacks a `size()` member function, where as the `sgi::slist` doesn't.  The motivation for this is that an O(N) `size()` has been problematic.  [N2543](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2543.htm) has more details on the design decisions for `forward_list`.

**Update:**

I recently had a good excuse to look closer at this subject.  `slist` also has other member functions that one would be tempted to think are O(1), but are really O(N).  These include:

```
iterator previous(iterator pos);
const_iterator previous(const_iterator pos) const;
iterator insert(iterator pos, const value_type& x);
iterator erase(iterator pos);
void splice(iterator position, slist& x);
void splice(iterator position, slist& x, iterator i);
```

In short, if you're not **very** careful, you can end up with significant performance problems by using `slist`.  Use of `std::forward_list` instead ensures that you'll get the expected O(1) performance out of your singly linked list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was interesting to read that paper. I agree with the decision not to include a size() member function. I suppose if I must know the size I can use std::list.

Answer (score 3):

So put simply, sgi::slist and forward_list are very similar.

The differences being that forward_list lacks a size() member function which is included in sgi::slist and forward_list includes an emplace_after member function which isn't included in sgi::slist. Also, forward_list doesn't provide insert and erase member functions like sgi::slist does.

If you know of any other differences, please don't hesitate to mention them.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently run into another difference. The method `splice_after` has a different interface and different behaviour.

1) forward_list Requires you to pass the container you're moving from as a second argument:

```
void splice_after( const_iterator pos, forward_list& other,
                   const_iterator first, const_iterator last );
```

slist:

```
void splice_after(iterator pos, iterator before_first, iterator before_last)
```

This is similar for the overloads.

2) Specific for the overload mentioned above: the last iterator is interpreted differently! Where slist moves the range [ before_first + 1, before_last + 1 >, forward_list moves the range < first, last >. So, when converting code (since slist is deprecated in GCC, for instance), make sure to use: last = before_last + 1.