# What's happened to slistS in BGL?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-graph

I'm using Boost 1.60 `adjacency_list` and would like to use `slistS` for the template parameter `OutEdgeList`:

```
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<
                 boost::slistS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS
              >;
```

This does not compile. Looking at [adjacency_list.hpp](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp) it seems this type is explicitly removed in absence of the old STL `std::slist`:

```
#if !defined BOOST_NO_SLIST
#  ifdef BOOST_SLIST_HEADER
#    include BOOST_SLIST_HEADER
#  else
#    include <slist>
#  endif
#endif

#if !defined BOOST_NO_SLIST
   struct slistS {};
#endif
```

Is it not possible to use `std::forward_list` for `boost::slistS`? If not, are there any plans to include this in future releases of BGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to me to be specific for Clang/Libc++ where `<slist>` is missing. It's not a part of the c++ standard.

Compiling with GCC/libstdc++ is fine (tested with GCC 5.2 and c++14).

So I'd just use `boost::container::slist`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/985d91ace94672da)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/container/slist.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

#ifdef BOOST_NO_SLIST
namespace boost {
    struct slistS;

    template <class ValueType> struct container_gen<slistS, ValueType> {
        typedef boost::container::slist<ValueType> type;
    };

    template <> struct parallel_edge_traits<slistS> { typedef allow_parallel_edge_tag type; };
}
#endif

int main() {
    using namespace boost;
    adjacency_list<vecS, slistS> works_for_me;
}
```

Comment: Assuming example is supposed to use `slitstS` rather than `listS`? Also, do you know if it's possible/safe to use `std::forward_list` in place of `boost::slist`?

Comment: Yeah. Indeed. [As long as `.size()` is not required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885436/what-is-the-difference-between-stl-slist-and-c0x-forward-list) there is no reason why not

Comment: I think you're missing some `boost::graph_detail::container_traits` specialisations.

Comment: Possibly. There's documentation of the required things for custom container selectors. I'm cooking dinner right now:)

Comment: Sure, just thought it would be nice to complete the answer for future reference. Turns out `std::forward_list` can't be used as `.size()` is required. Thanks.

Comment: And after having checked, no the above is all you need to use `boost::container::slist`.

Comment: Try using `boost::add_edge`.

Comment: @Daniel what's your point? Try grepping the source code for `slistS`. You can always present a question with a SSCCE.

Comment: That `container_traits` are needed to use `add_edge` and `remove_edge`.

Comment: Show, don't tell. Why am I having to come up with the code? What does all this have to do with the question? Q. "What happened to `slistS`" A. "It got disabled on your platform because it doesn't provide `<slist>`". It wasn't changed [since september 18th 2000](https://github.com/boostorg/graph/blame/develop/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp#L56)

Comment: @Daniel I haven't tried it(and I won't), but maybe you just need [to define `push` and `erase`](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:custom-storage).